# How to add a hyphen "-" to separate each entered or clicked value in Textbox from many buttons in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, textbox

I'm a beginner to C# (WinForms), now I have a problem how do I add the "-" to separate each value that clicked or entered from different buttons.

Example:

```
btn1 = "01", btn2 = "02", btn3="03", btn4 = "04"
```

If I click the first button the insert 01 to the TextBox, and if I also click the second button then insert 02 to the textbox again but the TextBox format should be 01-02 and so on.

How do I handle this statement in C#?

Edit: Here are the code I have tried:

```
private void txtFixedTypeTwo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sVal = txtFixedTypeTwo.Text;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sVal))
        {
            if(txtFixedTypeTwo.Text.Length <= 11)
            {
                var cVal = sVal.Substring(sVal.Length - 2);
                string nVal = sVal + "-" + cVal;
                txtFixedTypeTwo.Text = nVal;
                txtFixedTypeTwo.SelectionStart = txtFixedTypeTwo.Text.Length;
                txtFixedTypeTwo.Focus();
            }

        }
    }
```

The Button click event I do like this:

```
private void btn01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (focusedTextbox != null)
        {
            // put something in textbox
           focusedTextbox.Text += "01";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well, there's `string.Concat`

Comment: The `TextBox` is fundamentally the wrong control for this. Use a `ListBox` or `GridView` or something; any control that is designed to represent multiple values will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox.Text.Length > 0)
         textBox.Text += "-";

    Button butt = (Button)sender;

    textBox.Text += butt.Text;
}
```

From what I understood you have Button.Text= 01,02 and so on. You need to add this event click for all the buttons.

```
Button butt = (Button)sender;
```

With this line you are taking the button which is clicked.

Comment: The value that assigned for each button is from the button click event.

Comment: okay add 6 Button_clicks and instead butt.Text write it with "01", "02" and so on. the key line is if(textBox.Text.Length > 0)
         textBox.Text += "-";

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
        Action<string> append = t =>
            textBox.Text +=
                (textBox.Text.Length > 0 ? "-" : "") + t;

        btn1.Click += (s, _) => append("01");
        btn2.Click += (s, _) => append("02");
        btn3.Click += (s, _) => append("03");
        btn4.Click += (s, _) => append("04");
```

Just add this code into the `Form1_Load` method

Comment: this is a very elegant solution! using lambda operator, should be pick as correct answer! can you explain the meaning of (s, _), what is _ means?

Comment: @Tim - The `(s, _)` are just the two parameters for the standard event pattern - the sender and  event args. I couldn't use `(s, e)` because I suggested putting this code in the `Form_Load` method and it already defines `e` as its parameter. The use of `_` is just a valid variable name and I could have easily used `e2` or just `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(textBox1.Text.Length >= 2)
{
    textBox1.Text += "-00"
}
else
{
    textBox1.Text += "00"
}
```

> What will happen is when the length of `TextBox` is greater than equal to 2 it will add "-".

First Click `00` Second Click `00-00` Third Click `00-00-00`.

To prevent repetition, you need to create method.

```
void TextBoxValue(object sender, TextBox textBox, string value)
{
    if(textBox.Text.Length >= 2)
    {
        textBox.Text += String.Format("-{0}", value)
    }
    else
    {
        textBox.Text += value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @CeebLajThoj Yup, but you can make a solution to extend it.

Comment: So that how to do if there are unlimited length? please!

Comment: @CeebLajThoj You can adjust the `TextBox.MaxLength`?